# $G$- space is locally compact

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Suppose $X$ is a topological space ,$G$ Is a locally compact group.If the quotient space $G\backslash X$ is compact,can we deduce that $X$ is locally compact?

Comment: Is $G$ a group?

Comment: Sorry,it was a typo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take $X=$ any non-locally compact topological group, $G=$ the same group made discrete and acting on $X$ by left translations.

Comment: If $X$ is a proper $G$-space and $G\backslash X$ is compact,$G$ is locally compact,can we deduce that $X$ is locally comapct?

Comment: Just take $X'=X \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ (e.g. two copies of the space $X$), $G=X$ and the same argument follows.

Comment: @Bullet51,I saw the conclusion from the note:classifying space and proper actions.It mentions that :since $G$ is locally compact,every $G$-compact,proper $G$-space is locally compact.

Comment: Sorry, I misconceived the notion of "proper".

Comment: @Bullet51,how to prove the conclusion,would you mind showing me the details?